# Склеить два массива через третий массив

Tags: c#, массивы

**Задача:** Создать два массива и вывести их значение через третий пустой массив, не используя сложение как «+».

**Результат должен быть:**

a1b2c3d4e5

Пожалуйста, помогите написать простой код для таких чайников, как я, заранее спасибо!

```
string[] name = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "b", "d" };
string[] num = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

string[] all = new string[10];

for (int a = 0; a < all.Length; a++)         
     Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: `var result = string.Concat(name.Zip(num, (f, s) => new[] { f, s }).SelectMany(x => x));`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - аплодирую стоя Вашему варианту, я тоже сразу вспомнил про Zip!

Answer (score 1):

Одной строчкой:

```
string[] all = string[]{name[0], num[0], name[1], num[1], name[2], num[2], name[3], num[3], name[4], num[4]};
```

Вывести:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.Write(all[i]);
```

**Совет**: Используйте тип `char` вместо `string` в подобных случаях.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] name = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
string[] num = new string[5] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };

string[] all = new string[10];

int j = 0, k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < all.Length; i++)         
     if (i % 2 == 0) 
     {
         all[i] = name[j];
         j++;
     }
     else
     {
         all[i] = num[k];
         k++;
     }

for (int i = 0; i < all.Length; i++)
     Console.Write(all[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < all.Length;)
    all[i] = (i++ % 2 == 0 ? name[j] : num[j++]);
```

**Вариант 2**

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
{
    all[i*2] = name[i];
    all[i*2+1] = num[i];
}
```